# Noise Removing from Image with circular objects

Tags: image-processing, noise-reduction

What would be a good method to remove this type of noise from an image?

[image]

Comment: That seems far too broad for SO... you didn't even specify what programming language you are using.

Comment: I think programming language doesn't matter as long as I am using the right method

Answer (score 3):

Morphological closing (dilation then eorsion) with a structuring element larger than the stroke achieves this:

[image]

It won't be possible to completely get rid of the residual irregularities.

Comment: Thanks for your comments

Comment: Hi Yves. Could you show the structuring element you used please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: an octagon. A disk is even better. But this works for these round shapes.

Comment: Thank you - I hope you won't mind if I try to illustrate your answer.

Comment: Note that the larger the structuring element, the more of the “residual irregularities” you remove. Ideally you’d use a circular SE of the same size as the circles in the image (assuming they are perfect), then there would be none of the noise left.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: this is dangerous. One pixel more, and all the circles disappear.

Comment: for me, 9x9 structuring element works good but not 100 percent accurate though.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not accept this answer, and if you vote for it, please also vote for Yves's answer since I am merely illustrating how to implement his method and the credit is due to him.

So, you can just use **ImageMagick** at the command-line to do as Yves suggested like this:

```
convert ~/Desktop/utRjy.jpg  -morphology close octagon:13 result.png
```

[image]

Comment: That should actually be `close`, not `dilate`, to replicate Yves' result.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you, I have updated it. It looked back-to-front because ImageMagick considers white objects as foregrounds on black backgrounds.